# Using Flask and session to register a user. Am I understanding this correctly and writing clean code?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask

Good day everyone,

I am trying to get the form data from /register page and get a user registered. this is a part of my project given by CS50's web programming course and I am clueless since it doesn't seem to work seamlessly and the code looks somehow dirty. I would like to ask a code review on this and the restriction is that I can't be using ORM and only allowed to use sessions.

Have I done this correctly? am I at least close to writing a functioning code?

```
@app.route("/register", methods=['GET','POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # check if username and email exist
        username = request.form.get("username")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        u = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username",{"username": username}).fetchone()
        if u is not None:
            return "username already exists"
        u = db.execute("SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = :email",{"email": email}).fetchone()
        if u is not None:
            return "email already exists"
        # check if password and confirm_password match
        if request.form.get("password") != request.form.get("confirm_password"):
            return "password do not match"
    # insert user if statisfy all requirements
        hashed_password = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
        db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, email, password) VALUES (:username, :email, :password)",
        {"username": username, "email": email, "password": hashed_password})
        db.commit()
    # render login page once registerd
    return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: did you run it ? did you get error message when you test with many users ?

Comment: you get first user from database but correct user can be in other row. But after that you compare value from form with variables `username/email` which don't exist. Your code should gives you errors. Did you test it?

Comment: @furas I wasn't able to test it actually, I've updated the code if that helps.. I am just in the office where it is a little difficult to run the server at this moment.

Comment: @furas should i be declaring the variables for username/email? I merely thought that if I do the 'db.execute' part it will automatically declare the variables.. I guess I am wrong, should I be using for loops for this?

Comment: If any credential is wrong, you should return something like "Invalid Credentials". Saying "invalid password" lets the attacker know that the username or email is valid. Then they brute force the password.

Comment: not, it doesn't create variables you have to assing to variable - ie. `all_users = db.excute`  But using `fetchall()` it will not work too because it gives you all users and you would have to use `for`-loop to check every user with `get("username")`, etc. You would have to use ``get("username")` in SQL query like `SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username=? and email=?` and it should gives you zero (if user doesn't exists) or one result (if user exists) or many results (if you have mistake in database)

Comment: @furas could you give me an conceptual example of an appropriate loop for this? is this to compare every single entry of a column to compare the user input?

Comment: @furas I have tried a loop. What do you think?

Comment: if you use loop then better `for user in u:  user['username'] ...`. But there is no need to check it because SQL already made it in `WHERE ....` so you get only users with correct `username` and `email`. You have to only check how many results you get: `if len(u) == 0: user not exists`, `if len(u) == 1: user already exists` , `if len(u) > 1: mistake in data in database !!!`

Comment: @furas thanks, I gave my last shot..... lol

Comment: you can check only `len(u)` because `u` is a list with many results. In SQL is `username AND email`, not `username OR email` so this list has only users with correct username and email. To check how many users have the same username and how many users have the same email you would use two separated SQL - one with `WHERE username =?` and second with `WHERE email=?` and then you can use `len(u)` for every query.

Comment: In query you can also use `SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE ...` to get number and then you can check `u >= 1` without `len()` . BTW: it need `fetchone()`

Comment: @furas can I use .rowcount instead of .fetchone()? Thanks!

Comment: no, when you use `count(*)` then you need this value, not number of rows. It will return alwasy one value.

Comment: @furas could you have a look at the updated code one last time?